# Keeping score of a tic tac toe game and resetting Python

Tags: python

I am completely new to programming and had a quick question. I followed the directions of a Youtube video and got this tic tac toe game working and I wanted to do a couple of things that I have absolutely no idea how to approach.

1. Restart the game itself
2. How to add a scoreboard after the game ends for each player
3. How to reset said scoreboard

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this, except maybe keeping track of when players obtain a straight line and maybe do an "if" statement then +1 on a scoreboard? and print that later?

And in order to restart the game itself, would I just be using a boolean and put it on a loop?

I am so sorry these questions are extremely basic, but this is my first programming language. I would appreciate any help in the most basic forms of explanation!

Here is my [code](https://pastebin.com/NggmjV3D):

```py
#Gameboard
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]
 
#variables
game_going = True
 
winner = None
 
current_player = "X"
 
 
 
def display_board():
  print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " +board[2])
  print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " +board[5])
  print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " +board[8])
 
#recall
def play_game():
 
  display_board()
 
  while game_going:
    handle_turn(current_player)
 
    check_gameover()
 
    flip_turns()
 
  if winner == "X" or winner == "O":
    print(winner + " won!")
  elif winner == None:
    print("Tie!")
 
#turns
def handle_turn(player):
 
  print(player + "'s turn.")
  position = input("Choose a position from 1-9:")
 
  valid = False
  while not valid:
 
    while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
      position = input("Invalid input, choose a position from 1-9:")
 
    position = int(position) - 1
 
    if board[position] == "-":
      valid = True
    else:
      print("You can't go there. Go again.")
 
 
  board[position] = player
 
  display_board()
 
 
#checkgame
def check_gameover():
  check_win()
  check_tie()
 
 
 
#checkwin
def check_win():
 
  global winner
 
 
  #checkforrowscolumnsordiag
  row_winner = check_rows()
  column_winner = check_columns()
  diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()
  if row_winner:
    winner = row_winner
  elif column_winner:
    winner = column_winner
  elif diagonal_winner:
    winner = diagonal_winner
  else:
    winner = None
  return
 
def check_rows():
  global game_going
  row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
  row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
  row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"
 
  if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
    game_going = False
  if row_1:
    return board[0]
  elif row_2:
    return board[3]
  elif row_3:
    return board[6]
  return
 
def check_columns():
  global game_going
  column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "-"
  column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "-"
  column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "-"
 
  if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
    game_going = False
  if column_1:
    return board[0]
  elif column_2:
    return board[1]
  elif column_3:
    return board[2]
  return
 
def check_diagonals():
  global game_going
  diagonals_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "-"
  diagonals_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "-"
 
 
  if diagonals_1 or diagonals_2:
    game_going = False
  if diagonals_1:
    return board[0]
  elif diagonals_2:
    return board[6]
  return
 
#checktie
def check_tie():
  global game_going
  if "-" not in board:
    game_going = False
  return
 
def flip_turns():
  global current_player
  if current_player == "X":
    current_player= "O"
  elif current_player == "O":
    current_player = "X"
  return
 
play_game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probbably, this is a solution:

```py
# Gameboard
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]
 
# Variables
game_going = True
winner = None
current_player = "X"

# Score of players
score_x = 0
score_o = 0
 
# Print board
def display_board():
  print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " +board[2])
  print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " +board[5])
  print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " +board[8])
 
# Recall
def play_game():
  global score_x, score_o
 
  display_board()
 
  while game_going:
    handle_turn(current_player)
 
    check_gameover()
 
    flip_turns()
 
  if winner == "X":
    score_x += 1
    print("X won!")
  else if winner == "O":
    score_o += 1
    print("O won!")
  elif winner == None:
    # No one gains points
    print("Tie!")
 
# Turns
def handle_turn(player):
 
  print(player + "'s turn.")
  position = input("Choose a position from 1-9:")
 
  valid = False
  while not valid:
 
    while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
      position = input("Invalid input, choose a position from 1-9:")
 
    position = int(position) - 1
 
    if board[position] == "-":
      valid = True
    else:
      print("You can't go there. Go again.")
 
 
  board[position] = player
 
  display_board()
 
 
# Checkgame
def check_gameover():
  check_win()
  check_tie()
 
 
 
# Check win
def check_win():
 
  global winner
 
 
  # Check for rows, columns, or diagonals
  row_winner = check_rows()
  column_winner = check_columns()
  diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()
  if row_winner:
    winner = row_winner
  elif column_winner:
    winner = column_winner
  elif diagonal_winner:
    winner = diagonal_winner
  else:
    winner = None
  return
 
def check_rows():
  global game_going
  row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
  row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
  row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"
 
  if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
    game_going = False
  if row_1:
    return board[0]
  elif row_2:
    return board[3]
  elif row_3:
    return board[6]
  return
 
def check_columns():
  global game_going
  column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != "-"
  column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != "-"
  column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != "-"
 
  if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
    game_going = False
  if column_1:
    return board[0]
  elif column_2:
    return board[1]
  elif column_3:
    return board[2]
  return
 
def check_diagonals():
  global game_going
  diagonals_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "-"
  diagonals_2 = board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "-"
 
 
  if diagonals_1 or diagonals_2:
    game_going = False
  if diagonals_1:
    return board[0]
  elif diagonals_2:
    return board[6]
  return
 
# Check tie
def check_tie():
  global game_going
  if "-" not in board:
    game_going = False
  return
 
def flip_turns():
  global current_player
  if current_player == "X":
    current_player= "O"
  elif current_player == "O":
    current_player = "X"
  return

# Play again
while True:
  play_game()
  
  # Print score after game end
  print("Player O gained " + str(score_o) + " points")
  print("Player X gained " + str(score_x) + " points")
  
  # TODO: Add support for "no", "N" and so on
  if input("Play again (y/n): ") == "n":
    break;

  # Reset gameboard
  board = ["-", "-", "-",
           "-", "-", "-",
           "-", "-", "-"]
 
  # Variables too
  game_going = True
  winner = None
  current_player = "X"

  # Reset scores
  # TODO: Add support for "yes", "Y"
  if input("Reset score (y/n): ") == "y":
    score_x = 0
    score_y = 0
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 158, in <module>
    play_game()
  File "main.py", line 37, in play_game
    score_o += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score_o' referenced before assignment

Comment: I got this error when I ran this code, I think it's saying that score_o is used before defined correct?

Comment: Fixed. I've missed `global`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart the game itself

This one is fairly straightforward since you already have a function `play_game()`. You'll just need to call that function again after the game ends. Common patterns for doing so would be

```py
While True:
    play_game()
```

or you could implement a simple menu and ask the user if they want to play again

```py
def menu():
    print("Main menu")
    print("Enter a number to continue")
    print("1 - play game")
    print("2 - exit")
    
    # strip() removes all whitespace from the input String
    choice = input("> ").strip()
    
    if choice == "1":
        play_game()
    elif choice == "2":
        exit() # exit program
    else: 
        print("Invalid option, try again")

while True:
    menu()
```

Now the only problem with these solutions is that the `board`, `game_going`, `winner` and `current_player` variables won't be reset when you play again.
To solve this, you could set the value of these variables at the beginning of the `play_game()` function.

Note that in general, having variables defined globally is considered bad practice. To improve your solution I'd recommend learning about variable scope, and passing variables as parameters to your functions. https://pythonspot.com/scope/

---

2. How to add a scoreboard after the game ends for each player

To solve this, we want to keep track of the number of wins per player. We can use some variable for this, `x_wins = 0` `y_wins = 0`. And we need to update it when a player wins. So as you suggested, an `if` statement will suffice.

```py
if winner == "x":
    x_wins = x_wins + 1
```

This should go somewhere at the end of your `play_game()` function. And of course you can just print the scoreboard however you like after each game

```py
print("X has won " + x_wins + " times!")
```

A problem with this solution is that if you wanted to have players enter their names, and show a scoreboard based on the names entered, you wouldn't have a variable `david_wins` to represent them. To solve that and improve this solution you can look into better data structures that can hold any number of players, and their wins in a single variable. One very popular data structure for this is a dictionary, (outside of python, it's sometimes called a map) https://pythonspot.com/python-dictionaries/

---

3. How to reset said scoreboard

To reset the scoreboard, you only need to reset the value of your variables that represent the players.

```py
x_wins = 0
y_wins = 0
```

And this might be a function that you add to your main menu.

---

Another feature you can add that you may have had in mind, was keeping the scoreboard even after you restart the program. To implement this, you'll need to write the scoreboard to a file every time you exit your program, and read it again when you start up. So this would be a good opportunity to learn about file IO https://pythonspot.com/read-file/ https://pythonspot.com/write-file/

Comment: So I added the variables in the beginning of Play-game and I got this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 168, in <module>
    menu()
  File "main.py", line 161, in menu
    play_game()
  File "main.py", line 27, in play_game
    handle_turn(current_player)
  File "main.py", line 52, in handle_turn
    if board[position] == "-":
NameError: name 'board' is not defined

Comment: @DavidLee The error says it can't find the variable named `board`. That's likely because you've defined it outside the function. In order to access variables defined outside of your function you can either 1) use `global board` to tell python this is a global variable, or 2) pass board as a parameter to your function.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was very useful in helping me understand python better